# case insensitive openlayers filter not working

Tags: filter, openlayers, case-insensitive, geoserver

I have the following filter in openlayers 2.13

```
var filter_c = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
    property: 'strToLowerCase(p_name)',
    value: '%'+String(document.getElementById("nm").value).toLowerCase()+'%'
});

//pass the filter to the layer
var prot =  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
    featureType: "pins",
    featureNS: "http://www.mysite.gr",
    defaultFilter: filter_cl
});

var _CallBack = function(resp) {
    pins.addFeatures(resp.features)
    var cb = pins.features.length;
    if (cb == 0){alert("Nothing Found");}
};

var response = prot.read({callback: _CallBack});


//refresh to render POIs
pins.refresh({force:true});
```

I also use Geoserver 2.1.3 and PostgreSQL 9.1 /PostGIS 2.0.

This filter is case sensitive. **How can I make this filter case insensitive?**

The `pins` layer takes data from a table in postgreSQL/PostGIS. Names are in UTF8 and are Greek words, such as `Ακρόπολη`, `Παρθενώνας` etc.

I simply set it like `pins = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("LayerTitle", {renderers: ["Canvas", "SVG", "VML"]})` and the I have the aforementioned code to search it.

When I use the filter I don't get the `Nothing found` alert, but I see no points on the map and the map zooms 100% in the center. So, the filter kind of works. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you pass in OpenLayers are sent to GeoServer, so the query is made by geoserver and not OpenLayers.

You need to look at Geoserver docs to see how it can make case-insensitive queries. See http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html maybe the `matchCase` attribute can help.